# Are the Fracture Rune and Mirror Image exclusive?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

There are 2 ways to get mirror image as wizard in diablo 3

- Mirror image
- Teleport (with Fracture Rune).

Every time I cast normal mirror image, the mirror image from teleport goes out.

I sometimes do this quickly to make sure that the teleport mirror images doesn't go out simply because they expire.

They do.

What am I missing?

Basically I am experimenting with illusionist and try to tank monster by casting tons and tons of mirror image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one set of images up at a time.  Every time you cast either [Mirror Image](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/mirror-image) or [Teleport](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/teleport) (using the Fracture rune), it will summon up new images and unsummon the old ones.

If your goal is to be able to stand and tank stuff, I would go with Mirror Image (duplicates) with the Illusionist Passive.  You get six copies of yourself to tank/distract the enemies, and every time you get hit, you can recast it.

I used that through act 1 (until I got over geared and could just [Archon](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/archon) my way through everything).  It works very well, especially in the Halls of Agony, where the corridors are very tight.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work. You can only have one set of mirrors in the game apparently.